# PHP, how to read a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I do `var_dump($this->reports);`

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(15) {
["Terry CS"]=>
array(1) {
["2011-10-26"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "69.90"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "69.90"
}
}
["2011-10-27"]=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "199.50"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "199.50"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "69.90"
}
}
["Lisa CS"]=>
array(1) {
["2011-10-26"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "69.90"
}
}
}
```

how do I read through it so I can data in a table or list?

thanks

Comment: Why do you call it an OO array?

Comment: Just a normal array. Use `print_r()` instead of `var_dump()` for less confusing overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use foreach to iterate on an array:

```
foreach ($this->reports as $key => &$value) {
    var_dump($key, $value); 
}
```

If you want access to a specific data you can do this:

```
var_dump($this->reports["Terry CS"]);
```

More information [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is gather the data in order to print it in some tabular form, take a look at the PHP Manual, section [foreach](http://cl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).